# Concerning Silver's result

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Jack Silver proved that if $x$ is a real so that every $x$-admissible ordinal is a cardinal in $L$, then $0^{\sharp}$ exists.

I wonder whether various weaker or stronger  versions of Silver's result have been considered in the literature. For example,

$\bf{Question \ 1.}$:
How strong is the statement that there is real $x$ so that every $x$-admissible ordinal is a recursively inaccessible?

$\bf{Question \ 2.}$:
How strong is the statement that there is real $x$ so that every $x$-admissible ordinal is inaccessible in L?

Comment: Regarding question 2, do we know whether the $0^\sharp$-admissible ordinals are Silver indiscernibles?

Comment: Well, if $0^\sharp$ admissible ordinals are Silver indiscernibles, then they are inaccessible in $L$, which means for question 2 that there is no extra strength in asking for inaccessibility.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. I am not sure your question. What I know is that every $0^{\sharp}$-admissible ordinal is an $L$-cardinal

Comment: Wow, Nate Silver is everywhere these days.  (On a slightly more serious note, it's nice to give first and last name for someone who you cite, in case a curious novice is interested in searching for the individual to learn more about his work.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Re Q1: Sy Friedman has shown by class forcing over L that there can be consistently a real r
with the r-admissibles precisely the recursively inaccessibles.  (S Friedman, "Strong Coding" APAL, vol 35,1987).

Re Q2: All $0^\sharp$-admissibles are limits (indeed fixed points in the enumeration) of Silver indiscernibles (as can be seen by iterating the $0^\sharp$-mouse inside the least admissible set containing it). So 2 is not a strengthening.
One obtains strengthenings really by changing the model $L$ to some other inner model, such as a core model, for example $L^\mu$ the least inner model with a measurable cardinal.